# Create and invoke a function in run time, C#

Tags: c#, reflection

there is a way to create and invoke a function  in run time?
 for instance, how could I do to invoke this function?

```
    string function = @"public void Test(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int sum = num1 + num2;
            MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
        }";

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = null; // some code to create a method info from the string function
        method.Invoke(this, new object[] { 10, 20 });
```

All I could find were samples of System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod, but none use a function in a string

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples or search the web for "csharp scripting"

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class. It is fairly easy to use. Dynamic methods are invoked at fairly the same speed as compiled methods.